How do I create a notched nav bar with Expandable Floating Action Button
I want to combine a notched bottom app bar using the animated_bottom_navigation_bar package, and an expandable floating action button from the flutter_expandable_fab package.
Something like this:

Combined with this:

But passing in the Expanding FAB to this notched bottom nav bar doesn't work properly.
animated_bottom_navigation_bar: https://pub.dev/packages/animated_bottom_navigation_bar
flutter_expandable_fab: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_expandable_fab
